# Looking for documentation on ElasticSearch java node settings in V2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am unable to locate the documentation as to the settings that i can put in the following Settings instance and what each setting implies to the node client.

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
     .put("cluster.name",ESProperties.getInstance().getCacheClusterName())
        .put("http.enabled", "true")
        .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", "true")
        .put("discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout","60s")
        .build();

Client client = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().settings(settings)
        .client(true).node().client();
```

Can somebody help me locate those settings documentation?  I am developing common client for our enterprise usage and am badly in need of this listing to make it as a common component.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch settings are split per module, here's the list of modules :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules.html

Comment: It did not help me much.  My legacy code has a setting like this:
    .put("plugins.es-plugin.properties", true)
Dont know where to look for the explanation of this.